# Variable Ruby - Exercise from Launchschool

Tags: ruby

I am currently doing exercises from 
https://launchschool.com/books/ruby/read/variables#exercises and come across with this problem.

**Write a program called age.rb that asks a user how old they are and then tells them how old they will be in 10, 20, 30 and 40 years. Below is the output for someone 20 years old.**

Instead of writing puts many times, I want to write only three or four lines of code, however, my method is not working. Could you please check it? Thanks!

```
age = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "In 10 years you will be:"
puts age +  10
puts "In 20 years you will be:"
puts age +  20
puts "In 30 years you will be:"
puts age +  30
puts "In 40 years you will be:"
puts age +  40
```

````
ages = [30,40, 50, 60]

puts {In #{year} years you will be: #{age} age.}```
````

Answer (score 2):

You can prints all like this:

```
years = [10, 20, 30, 40]
years.each do |year|
  "In #{year} years you will be: #{age + year}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the puts logic inside a method

```
def ageOld(current_age)
  years = [10, 20, 30, 40]

  years.each do |year|
    puts "In #{year} years you will be: #{current_age + year}"
  end
end

age = gets.chomp.to_i
ageOld(age)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
def cal_age(current_age)
 years = [30,40, 50, 60]
 years.map {|i| puts "In #{i} years you will be: #{current_age + i} age." }
end
```

Comment: What would be the reason to always return `[nil, nil, nil, nil]` from this method? (Downvote is not mine since it is still printing what was expected.)

Comment: `puts` returns `nil` and as I used `map` here, it is returning the array of `nil`

Comment: I understand what `puts` returns. I pointed out you abused `map` for simple iteration, there should be `each` instead.

Comment: I have no idea. The only glitch with this code is an improper use of `map` AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40].tap do |shift|
  age = gets.chomp.to_i  
  shift.each do |years|
    puts "In #{years} years you will be: #{age + years}"
  end
end
```